# Is it possible to mock a private static final String literal?

Tags: java, oracle, unit-testing, mocking, hsqldb

My guess for the question above is that it is not possible but I need a confirmation. So the problem is that there is an Oracle specific SELECT (ROWNUM and FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED keywords are used) in a private static final String.

```
private static final String REC_QUERY_SELECT = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ROWNUM <=1 for update skip locked";
```

I want to unittest it whit HSQL but HSQL doesn't know these Oracle keywords. I would like to modify the REC_QUERY_SELECT variable (modify the SELECT to a simpler one) but I cannot as it is final and String literal.
Is there a way to modify it? (I mustn't change the codebase, I just have to write unit tests). I tried this code too:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
field.set(null, newValue);
```

Comment: Why don't you copy your final String into another non-final string variable?

Comment: Constants known at compile time can be inlined by the javac compiler so even if you change the original, it won't change anywhere it is used.

Comment: If your original query needs to be changed to test it with HSQL then what is it you're testing?

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies! This SELECT is in the original codebase which retrieves some records and these entities are being processed. I want to test this processing mechanism but without using the Oracle database. That is the reason why I am using HSQL. And that's why this String should be changed.
I am not allowed to modify the original code as it is already in production.
Peter: do you have the same opinion that is not possible to modify it?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As a *compile-time contant* (see the JLS) the string will be copied into the call site at compile time, so changing the value at runtime may not help.

In general, you should treat targeting different databases the same in testing as you would in production. Same old quality software engineering, which generally does not involve reflection.

Comment: Thanks Tom! Do you mean that it cannot be resolved without changing the code that is being tested?

Comment: @Viktor The generated code will have a direct reference to the string value (IIRC, an `ldc` instruction pointing to the string contants in the class file). The field isn't accessed. You would need to alter the compiled code. You could make the static a non-compile-time constant, but I suggest taking a better route.

Answer (score 0):

with [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) you can modify byte-code of target class in-place, and use the modified class at runtime.

Comment: Wow, I haven't known this framework so far. This is the real heavy artillery! :)

Comment: special missions require special weapons :)